# Send TCP POST request at slower rate

Tags: delphi, indy

I have a function that uploads a file with a TIdHTTP Post request.  It uses a TIdMultiPartFormDataStream for the file so is using the function

```
function TIdCustomHTTP.Post(AURL: string; ASource: TIdMultiPartFormDataStream): string;
```

This part works correctly, but I'd like to slow the rate it is sending so it uses less bandwidth.

Is there a way to loop a writebytes call or something so I could stick some sleeps in the middle and slow it down?  I don't care about the response from the request.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Indy has a `TIdInterceptThrottler` component for this very purpose.  You can assign it to the `TIdHTTP.Intercept` property, and then set the `TIdInterceptThrottler.SendBitsPerSec` property as needed.